# Rust test keeps giving error. Do i need to include something for the tests?

Tags: rust

My code works in a file by itself but whenever I try to run the Rustlings quiz1.rs there is an error in the testing part of the code.

```
// GOAL OF PROGRAM
// Mary is buying apples. One apple usually costs 2 Rustbucks, but if you buy
// more than 40 at once, each apple only costs 1! Write a function that calculates
// the price of an order of apples given the order amount. No hints this time

fn calculate_apple_price(apples: i32){
    let mut price = 2;
    if apples >= 40 {
        price = 1;
    }
}

// Don't modify this function!
#[test]
fn verify_test() {
    let price1 = calculate_apple_price(35); 
    let price2 = calculate_apple_price(65); 

    assert_eq!(70, price1); // Error happens here 'no implementation for `{integer} == ()`'
    assert_eq!(65, price2);// Error happens here 'no implementation for `{integer} == ()`'
}
```

I googled the problem and tried rust explain, but i am new to Rust. Can someone explain this error in plain english?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to specify a return type to `fn calculate_apple_price`, `price1` and `price2` are filled with a zero-sized type (this can be confusing when your learning RUST).
You should try something like this

```rust
fn calculate_apple_price(apples: i32) -> i32 /* specify i32 as return type */ {
    let mut price = 2;
    if apples >= 40 {
        price = 1;
    }
    price // Return the price (the `return` keyword is optional in this case)
}
```

Comment: The fact that `()` is zero-sized is not really relevant - and likely would cause even more confusion here.

Comment: I edited the code portion in the original question with the goal of the program to clarify. Although, I have tried this method and the test runs, but fails. It should return 35, the price of the amt of apples at $1 but instead returns the price of '1'.

Comment: @DominicThomas The returned value being incorrect is a completely different question, but I would recommend that you pay close attention to the fact that you are being asked to calculate the price of an **order**, and think about what you would need to do to obtain the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously accepted answer is wrong.

Correct one:

```
fn calculate_apple_price(n:i32)-> i32 {
    if n > 40 {
        n 
    }else{
        n * 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was making the original functionality wrong. I was returning what the price of one apple would be for whatever amount. Instead I was supposed to return the final price of all apples. here is the function for that

```
fn calculate_apple_price(apples: i32) -> i32{
    let mut price = 0;
    if apples <= 40 {
        price = apples * 2
    } else {
        price = apples * 1
    }
    price 
}
```

Comment: Your function is OK but notice that the variable "price" is useless you could write `fn calculate_apple_price(apples: i32) -> i32{
    if apples <= 40 {
        apples * 2
    } else {
        apples * 1
    }
}`